# Mouseover .animate stops prior .animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, intercept

I have two different .animate functions..

1. Slides down the elements on document ready.
2. Adds mouseover effect to these same elements.

Problem here is that IF you happen to have your mouse over the area where the elements slide in on document ready, they will stop in the position where your mouse was in.

The goal of course is to let the elements slide on their own without any interruptions.

http://photoshopmesta.net/sic/theTest/slide.html

Another thing.. the mouseleave seems to move the element slightly higher position than it was before the mouseover...

Any ideas on the image load? I put code in that loads the image file on document ready. It loads the images as fast as it is able to, but i didnt think of it that the elements will still slide no matter if the image is loaded or not.. and of course theyre not loaded before the sliding action.. :/

Edit:

**Working example thanks to @entropo http://jsfiddle.net/PnHpk/7/** Though it might be so that the images disappear from there after some time so heres example with color backgrounds instead of images http://jsfiddle.net/PnHpk/8/

Comment: Unrelated, but FYI on your link: `GET http://photoshopmesta.net/sic/theTest/easing.js 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @entropo Its not like it affects anything since i got jquery ui there but thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/entropo/PnHpk/

This is a good practice when asking questions here because it helps people answer you with a working example.

Here's my take on getting it to work:
http://jsfiddle.net/entropo/PnHpk/7/

I take advantage of jQuery 1.5's new Deferred objects.
See:  [SO '`[jquery] deferred`' search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+deferred)

Also, this isn't exactly what I did (I preferred using `push` to make a `Promise` stack), but this is helpful: [Deferred promises and synchronizing jquery.animate()](http://www.elfsternberg.com/2011/02/14/jquery-fadeout-lot-fadein-deferred-promises-jqueryanimate/)

Comment: @lollero ... I did a few tweaks to it just now.  Looks to be working swimmingly.  There are comments in my example too.

Comment: I was hoping that the code would be something that i could somewhat understand but even so your code seems to be working perfectly.. :) so i guess deferred might be something to learn.... Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

The reason its doing that is because you have a .stop in the mouseover and mouseout.  Obviously it makes sense to have them there, so what you should do is set the mouseover and mouseout events *after* the onload animations have finished.

Also if you want to wait until the image is done loading to play the animation, then use the image's .load event rather than the document .ready event

Edit: The elements move up slightly after the mouseover because they initially start with a margin-top of 10px but the animation sets it to 0px on mouseout

Edit2:

Instead of using the preloader for that image, use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var img = document.createElement('img');

    img.onload = function()
    {
        console.log("%o finished loading", this);
        //Set mouseover/mouseout event here
    };

    img.src = 'linkit.png';
});
```

Comment: Actually.. removing stop makes no difference, that was the first thing in my mind but it still does it the same way..

How do i change that image loading to onload instead of document ready?

Right.. I forgot that margin: 10px;

Comment: ok, apparently i have to take that back.. i accidentally just removed the .stop from mouseleave, so.. But anyways, how do i achieve that what you said about to set mouseover and mouseout events after onload animations have finished? despite how it might look, I'm really not experienced with jquery at all..

Comment: As far as the image loading goes.. that works nicely, but the.. sliding thingie.. i cant seem to figure out how to group those functions and to trigger those two groups in sequence... ( as i dont see any point in triggering all of them separately in sequence )

What im thinking is.. if i could "group" all the sligin functions to gether and then the mouseover functions together and then make the latter function to fire away after the first one..
 http://photoshopmesta.net/sic/theTest/slide.html this is what i tried but as im just shooting in the dark here.. i screwed up the code.

Comment: .at least the script runs somewhat now.. except that the mouseover doesnt work... which means im not even close with it :D Any ideas?