# why delaying chain functions causes problem?

Tags: jquery

```
var currentImage = 0;
var images = new Array('Aerodynamics.jpg','ABC_news.jpg','yep.jpg'); 
var newImage = 'url(images/'+images[currentImage]+')'; 

function slideSwitch() {
   $('.inner_img').css('background-image',newImage).animate({opacity:1.0},4000).delay(2000)
    .animate({opacity:0.0},4000,function(){
        if(currentImage < images.length-1){
            currentImage++;
        }else{
            currentImage = 0;  
        };
    });
};
```

First animation goes fine, delay() works fine too, next animation for opacity back to 0 doesn't works correctly, I mean the object hasn't disappear yet it already triggers the callback function, please tell me what am I doing wrong

Comment: how are you triggering the slideSwitch function? It might be starting again before it has finished for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

`.animate()` is non-blocking, meaning that the next step in your chain (the delay) starts immediately, not after the animation is done.

With jQuery 1.5's [Deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), you can force blocking behavior on animations, by creating a `Deferred promise` which is only resolved when the animation completes.

I answered a question which does exactly this yesterday, see my answer here for an example: [Mouseover .animate stops prior .animate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586059/mouseover-animate-stops-prior-animate)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to attach the revert animation in an anonymous function.

```
function slideSwitch() {
   $('.inner_img').css('background-image',newImage)
        .animate({opacity:1.0},4000, function() {

           $(this).animate({opacity:0.0},4000,function(){
             if(currentImage < images.length-1){
               currentImage++;
             }else{
               currentImage = 0;  
            });
    });    
};
```